# PHP: While loop condition

Tags: php, while-loop

```
$result= db_query("SELECT dayoff FROM specificdayoff");
$node->frmdate = mktime(0,0,0, $node->frmdate['month'], $node->frmdate['day'],$node->frmdate['year']);
$node->todate = mktime(0,0,0, $node->todate['month'], $node->todate['day'],$node->todate['year']);
$node->dayoff = mktime(0,0,0, $node->dayoff['month'], $node->dayoff['day'],$node->dayoff['year']);
$data = $node->dayoff;
$frmdate = $node->frmdate;
$todate = $node->todate;    

$iii=0;
while($frmdate!=$todate)
{
    while($data= db_fetch_object($result))
    {
        if($frmdate==$data)
        {
            $iii++;
           //debug
        }

    }
    $frmdate=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $frmdate), date("d", $frmdate)+1, date("Y", $frmdate));
    //debug2     
   }
$diff=$iii
```

I need every element of `$frmdate` to be compared with all element of `$data`. but when I run this code, `$diff` keep returning 0. meaning to say, there's something wrong with my if statement, but I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with it.

when I debug this block of code, both while loop did not run as i want it. the 2nd while loop only run once. I need the 2nd while loop to be run every time 1st while loop is running. any help?

the debug run like this:
debug
debug
debug
debug2
debug2
debug2

i need it to run like this:
debug
debug
debug
debug2
debug
debug
debug
debug2
debug
debug
debug
debug2

Comment: It also looks like you are comparing an object (`$data`) to an integer (timestamp `$frmdate`). I would check what you are expecting from `db_fetch_object`

Comment: @BrendanLong cuz i do not want any addition to $iii when $frmdate not equal to $data

Comment: @Cooper - So just leave the `else` out. You don't need one. `if` statements are perfectly fine alone.

Comment: @phindmarsh do u know any way i could compare these two variable ($data, $frmdate). i expect db_fetch_object would fetch the 'dayoff' field in the database. the 'dayoff' field contains timestamp. i need to compare this dayoff field with $frmdate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling you have a timestamp in your `specificdayoff` table. If this is the case, then your `db_fetch_object` method will retrieve an object that has `dayoff` property.

To access this you would use `$data->dayoff`. So you need to change the condition of the `if($frmdate==$data)` to `if($frmdata == $data->dayoff)`

This is all a guess without knowing exactly what your db_fetch_object will return. That said, I still don't follow exactly what is supposed to be happening here, and this may just be one of a few problems you have.

Comment: omg! it work! you're the man. $data->dayoff could change $data to integer! my if statement are workin now. thanks for the help man.

Comment: @Cooper, no problem, I'm glad it helped. As mentioned above, if this or the other solution (by @Brendan) solves your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: both answer solves my problems. so i should mark both as accepted. right? sorry. a newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

You said the problem is this:

```
while($data= db_fetch_object($result))
```

What's happening is that after running through this loop once, you'll fetch all of the results, so there are none left. Going through the loop again, there's still no results because you already fetched them all. You need to set up `$result` again. You didn't include this, code but look for a line that looks like `$result = ...`.

Something like this:

```
$node->frmdate = mktime(0,0,0, $node->frmdate['month'], $node->frmdate['day'],$node->frmdate['year']);
$node->todate = mktime(0,0,0, $node->todate['month'], $node->todate['day'],$node->todate['year']);
$node->dayoff = mktime(0,0,0, $node->dayoff['month'], $node->dayoff['day'],$node->dayoff['year']);
$data = $node->dayoff;
$frmdate = $node->frmdate;
$todate = $node->todate;    

$iii=0;
while($frmdate!=$todate)
{
    $result= db_query("SELECT dayoff FROM specificdayoff");
    while($data= db_fetch_object($result))
    {
        if($frmdate==$data)
        {
            $iii++;
        }
    }
    $frmdate=mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", $frmdate), date("d", $frmdate)+1, date("Y", $frmdate));  
}
$diff=$iii
```

Comment: so, is there any function or way for me to make 2nd loop run everytime 1st loop is runnin? i already add variable declaration, query and debug result in the block of code.

Comment: @Cooper - Set `$result` inside the outer loop.

Comment: ohh. done! sorry. im still new. thanks for the help again brendan.

Answer (score 1):

$frmdate is a simple PHP timstamp, created by mktime(). You then compare this timestamp value agains an **OBJECT** created by a database fetch statement. A timestamp and a DB fetch object can never be equal, so your while loop's `$iii++` can never get triggered.

Comment: no wonder i get 0 all the time. I've find the way to convert the fetch_object into timestamp so that it could be compared with $frmdate! thanks mate!